# Django heroku uploading files

Tags: python, html, css, django, heroku

> [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/static_in_env'

I am new to heroku, when I push my django application on heroku, I can't upload files, yet it is working properly in local computer!

Here is the error:

```
OSError at /admin/products/product/add/
[Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/static_in_env'
Request Method: POST
Django Version: 1.8
Exception Type: OSError
Exception Value:    
[Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/static_in_env'
Exception Location: /app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/os.py in makedirs, line 157
Python Executable:  /app/.heroku/python/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.12
Python Path:    
['/app',
 '/app/.heroku/python/bin',
 '/app',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python27.zip',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-25.2.0-py2.7.egg',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.2-py2.7.egg']
Server time:    Sat, 10 Sep 2016 10:14:54 +0000
```

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, Heroku does not host your application Media files. So what you need is to pick up a third party service like AWS S3 to store data in the cloud.

Below is the official guide of how you can deal with Django applications media files on Heroku.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3-upload-python

Reminder: Django "media" files are files that have been uploaded by web site users, that then need to be served from your site.